# I need Microsoft SQL Clustering/Replication/Scaling Best Practice Resources

Tags: sql-server, scaling

I'm trying to plan for our future scalability of our Microsoft SQL 2000/2005/2008 infrastructure. I'm having a hard time finding good information on how to best engineer such services, how to best keep these services available, and how to scale them as load increases. Can someone point me in the right direction? Books, online resources, videos, anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The folks at SQL Skills (Kimberly Tripp, Paul Randal, Bob Beauchemin, Stacia Misner) keep a relatively current list of all available Microsoft SQL Server whitepapers. You can find the list here:

http://www.sqlskills.com/whitepapers.asp

You'll probably want to check out the [High Availability with SQL Server 2008 whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523927.aspx) listed there (authored by Paul).

Comment: Perfect! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

microsoft.com/sql

look for the white papers they have all the scaling\infrastructure stuff documented.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the good pointers you already received, I suggest also the SQL Server Customer Advisory Tam site. They have plenty of studies and practical information from the field.

http://sqlcat.com